# Automated Scheduled Pull Request in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

So I know that are multiple posts out there but not sure they covered my issue. So I have two branches dev and QA, I would like to do a NIGHTLY merge from dev to QA. I dont know how to go about doing this to setup a nightly pull request from dev into qa. Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how to go about doing this to setup a nightly pull request from dev into qa

Based on your requirement, you could setup [schedule trigger Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in Azure Devops.

[image]

Then you could add the task: Create Pull Request  from [Create Pull Request Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest).

[image]

When the specified time is reached, it will trigger the pipeline and create a pull request. You could set the auto-complete in this task, then the pull request will complete.

Or you could write script to run the Rest API to create and complete pull request.

[Create- Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

[Update- Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)