# How to automate Azure DevOps Pull Request?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Hi I am trying to automate Pull Request in Azure DevOps and below are the steps I have followed

1. Created branch automatically
2. Updated files automatically
3. Commited changes back to repository automatically
4. Created Pull Request automatically
5. Approved Pull Request automatically
6. Set Auto Completed

I am stuck at the last point how to automatically complete it or marked it as completed

[image]

Comment: Could you please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729526/automated-scheduled-pull-request-in-azure-devops , may it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only can do a Auto-Complete before approving the PR. Did you approved before you took this image?

An Autocomplete is just a way to say to DevOps to complete your PR as soon as it is approve. Otherwise you must complete after the approval step

Comment: Yes @Lucas I am approving it before than marked it as autocomplete.

Comment: And voilà! 

The set autocomplete must be do before the approval step. 

You can try now if you want: make a new PR and set the auto complete (you don’t need to approve, just for the test…)

Comment: It's working thanks.

Comment: Great news! Please, mark as the correct answer. Glad to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Lucas now the whole process from creating branch to complete pull request is automated.

Comment: do you know how to auto approve it, I am using Rest API but getting `You cannot record a vote for someone else`

Comment: Look for your policies. Is there something blocking you? (directly in the portal)